# How can I produce a 3D space-time trajectory plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, mplot3d

Let's say I have 3 dataframes with info on latitudes, longitudes and timetag of  objects, such that every column represents a different object, and every row represents a point in time.

```
latitudes =
object          1            2            3                
0          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339       
1          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339     
2          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
3          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
4          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
5          -8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   


longitudes =
object          1            2            3         
0         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661     
1         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661     
2         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661    
3         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661   
4         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661    
5         -34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661   

times =
object  1                      2                     3                   
0       2016-03-05 07:52:00   2016-03-05 16:26:00   2016-03-05 16:58:00   
1       2016-03-05 08:19:00   2016-03-05 16:42:00   2016-03-05 17:45:00   
2       2016-03-05 08:52:00   2016-03-05 17:06:00   2016-03-05 17:58:00   
3       2016-03-05 09:36:00   2016-03-05 18:21:00   2016-03-05 18:23:00   
4           NaT               2016-03-05 23:06:00   2016-03-05 22:38:00   
5           NaT               2016-03-05 23:09:00       NaT
```

I would like to plot a 3D trajectory, with time on the z-axis, longitude on the x-axis, and latitude on the y-axis, where all the objects' trajectories are on the same plot. How can I do this?

This is my attempt but it does not work:

```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot(longitudes.values,latitudes.values,times.values)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Time')
    plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

Thank you

Comment: For 2d plots the third argument is reserved for the marker type, which is specified using a string. I think you are getting the default error message because the array times.values is not understood. What is the type o this array? It looks like datetimes or somth. Did you try to convert it to floats before calling plot?

Comment: it's actually an object, because there are some NaTs besides the datetime values.

Comment: I would suggest you provide a [mcve] of the issue that can be copied and run to reproduce the error. Otherwise solutions will need to make assumptions, which may or may not be valid in your case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the question and added 'NaT' values to the 'times' dataframe, so it should be MCV.

Comment: No, it's not a [mcve] and it took me quite some time to reproduce the issue. See my answer on how a [mcve] might look like - it can be copied and run.

Answer (score 4):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Time')

for t in times.columns:
    ax.plot(longitudes[t].values, latitudes[t].values, times[t].values, label='t')

ax.legend()
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnQ]Lm.png

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get the same error. My time dataframe is of type datetime. How did you convert it?

Comment: I also have 'NaT' in some time values, because the objects do not necessarily have the same number of time points, so that could be the reason for the error. idk

Answer (score 1):

You will need to filter out the NaT values, as they cannot be plotted.

```
latitudes = u"""                
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339       
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339     
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339   
-8.064267    -8.047483    -8.056339"""  


longitudes = u"""        
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661     
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661     
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661    
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661   
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661    
-34.878386   -34.904086   -34.889661""" 

times = u"""                
2016-03-05 07:52:00, 2016-03-05 16:26:00, 2016-03-05 16:58:00   
2016-03-05 08:19:00, 2016-03-05 16:42:00, 2016-03-05 17:45:00   
2016-03-05 08:52:00, 2016-03-05 17:06:00, 2016-03-05 17:58:00   
2016-03-05 09:36:00, 2016-03-05 18:21:00, 2016-03-05 18:23:00   
2016-03-05 09:36:00, 2016-03-05 23:06:00, 2016-03-05 22:38:00   
2016-03-05 09:36:00, 2016-03-05 23:09:00, 2016-03-05 09:36:00
"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

kw = dict(delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
latitudes = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(latitudes),**kw)
longitudes = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(longitudes),**kw)
times = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(times), delimiter=",",
                    infer_datetime_format=True,header=None)
times.iloc[4:,0] = None
times.iloc[5,2] = None

for i in times.columns:
    times[i] = pd.to_datetime(times[i], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

for t in times.columns:
    inx = times[t].values != None
    x = longitudes[t].values[inx]
    y = latitudes[t].values[inx]
    z = times[t].values[inx]
    ax.plot(x,y,z)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your method. This line still does not filter the NaT values: `inx = times[t].values != None`.

Comment: Well, I can only tell you that it does work as seen in the above answer. You may decide to finally provide a [mcve] of the issue, that makes the error reproducible.